# FedEx Api: Bad Request Error, Missing or duplicate parameters. Please modify your request and try again

Tags: php, rest, restful-authentication, fedex

For some reason, I'm getting a `400 Bad Request` error when I'm sending my authentication to FedEx for my API. Here is my code:

```
$payload = [
    'grant_type' => 'client_credentials',
    'client_id' => self::$apiKey,
    'client_secret' => self::$apiSecret,
];

$api = new App_ApiTransaction('POST', self::$authEndpoint, $payload, App_ApiTransaction::ENCODE_JSON);

$api->addHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
```

I tried using GET, but I was getting a `405` error. Also, this is a custom header function.

What could be causing the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution, here is what I had to do:

```
 $payload = ('grant_type=client_credentials&client_id='.self::$apiKey.'&client_secret='.self::$apiSecret);
```

Basically changed the Payload to the correct format